# Passing argument by reference

Tags: c++, reference

Having an array:

```
int a = { 1 ,2 , 3}
```

I can pass a pointer to a function in order to modify it.

```
int modify( int *a ){
   a[0] = 10;
}
```

But why can't I pass a reference to int to modify it? e.g

```
int modify( int &a ){
   a[0] = 10;
}
```

How does compiler manipulate with a reference? By using pointers, we pass the memory (in this case, the first element of the array ). But what happens with a reference? Why, for example, does this work?

```
vector<int > a 

void mod( vector<int> & a ){
      a[0] = 10;
     //a.push_back(10)
}
```

Comment: `int modify(int &a ){
   a = 10;
}`

Comment: you don't have an array. it should be `int a[] = {1,2,3};`

Answer (score 0):

> but why cant i pass reference to int to modify it?

You sure can.

The syntax needs to be a bit different for that.

```
int modify( int (&a)[3] ){
   a[0] = 10;
}
```

The difference between using

```
int modify( int *a ){ ... }
```

and

```
int modify( int (&a)[3] ){ ... }
```

is that you can call the first one using arrays of different sizes while the second one can be called only with arrays of size 3.